# Using Firebase Admin within Deno throwing HTTP 500 for https://esm.sh/v103/@firebase/database-compat@0.3.1/deno/standalone.js

Tags: javascript, firebase, deno

When attempting to build/deploy this Deno function,

```
import { serve } from "https://deno.land/std@0.171.0/http/server.ts";
import "https://deno.land/x/xhr@0.2.1/mod.ts";
import { installGlobals } from "https://deno.land/x/virtualstorage@0.1.0/mod.ts";
import admin from 'https://esm.sh/firebase-admin@11.5.0';
installGlobals();
const serviceAccount = Deno.env.get('service_account');

if (!serviceAccount) {
  throw new Error('service account details not available');
}

admin.initializeApp(JSON.parse(serviceAccount));

serve((_req) => {
  admin.database().ref('/test').set('Hi there');

  return new Response("Maybe done?", {
    headers: { "content-type": "text/plain" },
  });
});
```

I get the following error

> Import 'https://esm.sh/v103/@firebase/database-compat@0.3.1/deno/standalone.js' failed: 500 Internal Server Error
> at https://esm.sh/v103/firebase-admin@11.5.0/deno/database.js:2:901

Is there anything I can do to fix? Or do I have to find and use a different version of firebase-admin in the function?

Answer (score 0):

If you bring up the package on [unpkg](https://unpkg.com/browse/@firebase/database-compat@0.3.1/standalone/), you can see that the package exports this "standalone" module in a non-standard way.

```
@firebase/database-compat@0.3.1/
|-- dist/
| |-- database-compat/
| |-- node-esm/
| |-- index.esm2017.js
| |-- index.esm5.js
| |-- index.js
| |-- index.standalone.js  # @firebase/database-compat@0.3.1/standalone entry point
| `-- ...
|-- standalone/
| `-- package.json
|-- CHANGELOG.md
|-- README.md
`-- package.json
```

[esm.sh](https://esm.sh) does not appear to attempt to resolve the instructions contained in `@firebase/database-compat@0.3.1/standalone/package.json` instead thinking it should map to `@firebase/database-compat@0.3.1/standalone.js`. Because of this behaviour, we can tell `esm.sh` that we'd like to resolve our own copy of `@firebase/database-compat/standalone`.

```
https://esm.sh/firebase-admin@11.5.0?external=@firebase/database-compat/standalone
```

In the response from `esm.sh`, you'll see that the library is now imported using a label.

```js
// ...
import ___firebase_database_compat_standalone$ from "@firebase/database-compat/standalone";
// ...
```

You then need to add an entry into your `import_map.json` that tells Deno where it should get this file from:

```json
// import_map.json
{
  "imports": {
    "@firebase/database-compat/standalone": "SOME_URL",
    // ...
  }
}
```

Unfortunately I couldn't figure out the syntax needed to get this package to resolve because the following URLs didn't work (`?target=deno` allows me to resolve it in the browser to poke around). This seems to be a known bug (see [`ije/esm.sh/issues/356`](https://github.com/ije/esm.sh/issues/356)).

```
https://esm.sh/@firebase/database-compat@0.3.1/dist/index.standalone.js?target=deno
https://esm.sh/@firebase/database-compat@0.3.1/index.standalone.js?target=deno
https://esm.sh/@firebase/database-compat@0.3.1/standalone?target=deno
https://esm.sh/@firebase/database-compat@0.3.1/standalone/package.json?target=deno
```

Comment: Thank you so much. I'm very new to Deno and I'll admit that I don't immediately understand much of this, so I'm going to have to spend some time upacking it all. Thanks again